# When to create a new class in OOP?

Tags: class, oop, language-agnostic

I have experience in C programming, with the procedural way to solve problems using code. And I finally decided to learn OOP, since this is vastly used on modern languages. But I have a lot of trouble to understand how we should design our applications in this paradigm.

I’ll clarify what I mean: in C (procedural programming), we have a main function. We create new functions as needed and make calls to them to achieve what we want. This is how it works (in the shortest possible way).

And I can’t help but try to do the same thing in OOP languages. Every program I try to write, I create various functions and make calls to them in the main class. I don’t really know when to create new classes and how we know they are designed properly.

I though that programmers that use OOP languages creates lots of classes, use lot of inheritance, interfaces, abstract classes etc. everyday. But if I create three classes in a program is like a lot to me. Is this common? The three main pillars of OOP (encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism) are used that frequently?

And a personal recommendation if you could give me: what are good resources to learn OOP? Any site / blog, YT channel, book would be great. Because the thing I miss the most is references of good written code. All I see out there are basic examples like “cat class”, “mammal class”, “car class”. If someone could give me a tip to find nice references of more complex programs would help a lot! Thanks for any help :D

Comment: You can use Java, then everything has to be a class so you'll get lots of practice :)

Comment: Start with the SOLID principles.  They apply to all software development.  In an OOP language, you will use OOP constructs like interfaces and classes to implement them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: This is such a good question. I've been programming "OOP" for many years, and I still don't know the correct answer :D. My controversial opinion: forget about OOP and other principles you'll find online or in books. OOP is so confusing to people because it is not a programming technique, it is rather a design framework. You use all those principles like polymorphism and behavior encapsulation (not data encapsulation) to design your software, not to implement it. Also, small programs won't benefit from this approach, OOP was meant for large applications with much code reuse in mind.

Comment: Here is a great book to start your journey with OOP: [An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming
Third Edition
by Timothy A Budd](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~budd/Books/oopintro3e/info/ReadMe.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @berhalak ! I think that you said very well when you states that "You use all those principles like polymorphism and behavior encapsulation to **design** your software, not to implement it". Beacause all those principles come to my mind when I'm thinking about how the objects will interact with each other. In the planning stage of the project. Not when i'm writing code. Also, thank you very much for the book recommendation, i'm looking forward to read it!

Comment: Well, each time you have a `struct` and several functions operating on that `struct`, you have a potential candidate for a `class`. Keep in mind that objects encapsulate data *and* behavior, so a function alone is not a candidate for a class.